# actionscript 3, flash game ai, path OR automatic movement

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, artificial-intelligence, game-physics

I am creating a flash game and I've hit a problem

I have four objects, lets call them img1 through img4

I need them to move around a maze, witch is made up of blocks (maze.wall.block1 to block53)

I have seen tutorials on creating a path however these all involve the object to be added to the stage, where as I am doing it in a as3 class.

So my question is either:
How can I create a path manualy on the stage, then create an object to follow the path in the as3 class, OR how can I add very simple ai to the img object to move around but change direction when the hitTestObject triggers on the maze.wall.blocks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create your own pathfinding implementation since your game seems tile based? Trust me - it's pretty easy and rewarding!

This is the best article I have seen on pathfinding - it's easy to understand:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm)